# npm (v7.18.+) install, --workspaces flag needed?

Tags: npm-install, npm-workspaces

If I have a project with workspaces and use `npm install` on the root folder, do I need the `--workspaces` flag to install all workspaces, or is it used automatically?

It looks to me like npm install already does this automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you're right, `npm install` will install workspaces by default.

More info:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces#adding-dependencies-to-a-workspace
- https://ruanmartinelli.com/posts/npm-7-workspaces-1
- https://dev.to/limal/simplify-your-monorepo-with-npm-7-workspaces-5gmj

Comment: This is the relevant paragraph from the first link: "We also refer to these packages being auto-symlinked during npm install as a single workspace, meaning it's a nested package within the current local file system that is explicitly defined in the package.json workspaces configuration."